# django form is valid() fails

Tags: python, django, forms

I am trying to create a registration form using django, when I submit my form the is valid() function fails and I am not sure why. I have my registration and login page all on one html page, although, I have called all the field names different names, eg login_username.

forms.py

```
class SignUpForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Username', max_length=20,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Enter Username'}))
    conUsername = forms.CharField(label='Confirm Username', max_length=20,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Confirm Username'}))
    firstName = forms.CharField(label='First Name', max_length=20,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Enter Firstname'}))
    lastName = forms.CharField(label='Last Name', max_length=20,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Enter LastName'}))
    email = forms.CharField(label='Email', max_length=220,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Enter Email','type':'email'}))
    conEmail = forms.CharField(label='Confirm Email', max_length=220,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'Confirm Email','type':'email'}))
    password = forms.CharField(label="Confirm Password", max_length=20,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','type':'password','placeholder':'Enter Password'}))
    conPassword = forms.CharField(label="Confirm Password", max_length=20,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','type':'password','placeholder':'Confirm Password'}))
```

views.py

```
def SignUp(request):
    regForm = SignUpForm()
    form = LoginForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':

        if regForm.is_valid():
            username = regForm.cleaned_data('username')
            print username
            confirm_username = regForm.cleaned_data('conUsername')
            first_name = regForm.cleaned_data('firstName')
            last_name = regForm.cleaned_data('lastName')
            email = regForm.cleaned_data('email')
            confirm_email = regForm.cleaned_data('conEmail')
            password = regForm.cleaned_data('password')
            confirm_password = regForm.cleaned_data('conPassword')



                #try:
                    #user = User.objects.get(username=request.POST['username'])
                    #return render(request, 'index.html',{'error_message':'username must be unique'})
                #except User.DoesNotExist:  
                    #user = User.objects.create_user(request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
                    #login(request, user)
                    #return render(request, 'index.html')
        else: 
            return render(request,'index.html',{'username_error':'usernames didnt match','form':form,'regForm':regForm})


    else:
        return render(request, 'index.html',{'form':form,'regForm':regForm})
```

index.html

```
<form class="regForm" method="POST" action="{% url 'signup' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{username_error }}
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-8">
        <div class="form-group">
            {{regForm.error_message.username}}
           {{ regForm.username }}
        </div>
    </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 ">
    <div class="form-group">
      {{error_message.conUsername}}
           {{ regForm.conUsername }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-8">
        <div class="form-group">
           {{ regForm.firstName }}
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
           {{ regForm.lastName }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-8">
        <div class="form-group">
           {{ regForm.email }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-8">
        <div class="form-group">
           {{ regForm.conEmail }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-8">
        <div class="form-group">
           {{ regForm.password }}
        </div>
    </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
           {{ regForm.conPassword }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-9">
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" id="regBtn" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

      </form>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right now your form is always empty and therefore invalid. You forgot to add the request POST content to the form.

```
def SignUp(request):
    # ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        regForm = SignupForm(request.POST)  # form needs content
        if regForm.is_valid():
            # ...
```

If you get stuck when calling `.is_valid()`, you can `print(regForm.errors)` to see what's up.

Answer (score 2):

You have two main problems. Firstly, you are never passing the POST data to the form, so it can never be valid.

Secondly, for some reason you are ignoring everything that the form could tell you about why it is not valid, and always returning "usernames didn't match". What's more, you're not even doing anything to compare usernames, so that error message will never be accurate.

You should rework your view to follow the pattern as described in the documentation:

```
def SignUp(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        regForm = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if regForm.is_valid():
             ...
             return redirect(somewhere)
    else:
        regForm = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'regForm':regForm})
```

and in your template make sure you include `{{ form.errors }}` to show what the validation failures are.

Comment: I added the username_error message so something would be outputted to the screen so I could check to see if the form.is_valid function was working